# Xfce4: How to decide which application to open the url based on patterns

Tags: ubuntu, xfce, xdg

The system has a bunch of browsers (like Chromium and Brave). All urls are to be opened by Chromium. So brave is not the default application for that. However, I want youtube links to be opened by Brave and not chromium. How can I achieve this in my ubuntu with xfce4?

Note:  `xdg-mime query default x-scheme-handler/http` returns chromium, the problem is this is not about the scheme.